# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS won't power off or restart

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, shutdown, ideapad

i am having problems with shutting down Ubuntu. My device is set on dual boot. I don't have this problem with Windows 11. My device is an lenovo ideapad gaming 3 with ryzen5 5600H and Nvidia geforce rtx 3050. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjJq.jpg)